# assign array of pictureboxes to an event

Tags: c#, arrays, events, event-handling, picturebox

I have a array of pictureboxes like this:

```
PictureBox[] pb = new PictureBox[71]
{
pictureBox1,pictureBox2,pictureBox3,...etc
};
```

and I know how to assign a event to a single object,

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

but how can I assign this array to 1 event handler, the final result should be when I'm hovering 1 of the 71 boxes the .backColor property, instead of making 71 handlers for each picturebox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe the event handlers like so:

```
foreach (var p in pb)
{
    p.MouseHover += new EventHandler(pictureBox1_MouseHover);
}
```

And set the `BackColor` like so:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((PictureBox)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

`sender` is the actual PictureBox that fired the event.

Comment: thankyou, it works perfectly.
The only problem now is that i have a delay of 1 second before it turns red, any solution to speed up this process?

Comment: @timouwerker How fast do you want it? If you want it to be instantaneous, try `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` instead.